# Laravel Elixir BrowserSync not loading correct project from wamp directory

Tags: php, gulp, wamp, laravel-5.4

I have a new issue regarding the Laravel-Elixir-BrowserSync task.

Currently I set up a new laravel project in "C:\wamp64\www\projectname" but when I run my gulp watch command it does not load the project that I want to work on.
There is however a laravel blog application folder that I created to play around in laravel on my wamp setup so whenever I start wampserver it loads the laravel blog application or it just loads a blank webpage that keeps loading all the time.

Should I just remove the blog folder permanently from the wamp/www folder or how can I change this to load the specific project I want to work on?

My gulp file looks like this.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var vueify = require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

elixir(function (mix) {

  // compile all .scss files into this main file
  mix.sass('app.scss');
  mix.sass('main.scss');
  mix.scripts('app.js');
  mix.browserify('app.js');

  mix.browserSync({
    proxy: 'dev.myprojectname',
    port: 5000 
  });

  // export it into the public folder here.
  mix.version('public/css/app.css');
  mix.version('public/css/main.css');
  mix.version('public/js/app.js');

  mix.phpUnit();
  mix.phpSpec();

});
```

Comment: When I run the php artisan serve command it brings up the correct project as I am serving the project from the correct folder in command line but I do not want to use php artisan serve.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I found that there was an error in my httpd-vhosts.conf file where the DocumentRoot was missing (I deleted the project) so I just set it to the new folder path for the site I want to serve when running my gulp watch file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/project-name/public
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

```
mix.browserSync({
  proxy: 'local.dev',
  port: 5000
});
```